# how to write query to check another table based on condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an order_status table like so:

```
order_id   order_status
1          100
2          1000
3          1000
```

I have another table order_status_history which stores historical data for order:

```
id  order_id   order_status  status_date
1   1          100           2016-01-01
2   2          100           2016-02-01
3   2          300           2016-04-01
4   3          100           2016-04-01
5   3          400           2016-04-01
6   3          1000          2016-04-01
7   2          1000          2016-05-01
```

I am trying to build a daily report, where for a given date, I want to see if an order was completed or in progress. I am pretty bad with SQL and not able to figure out how to do it. If for a date, the status of the order is < 1000 then it is in progress, else it is completed.

Eg: For date 2016-04-01, the report would be:

```
order_id    status
1           in-progress (because as of report date, its latest status is 100)
2           in-progress (because as of report date, its latest status is 300)
3           completed   (because as of report date, its latest status is 1000)
```

I am trying something like following to try to at least find in progress orders:

```
select distinct s.order_id, s.order_status
from order_status 
    left join order_status_history h on h.order_id = s.order_id
where max(h.status_date) <'2016-04-01'
  and status < 1000
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the current status in the order_status table also on the history table?

Comment: The `order_status` table doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your statuses mean.  But for a given order they seem to always be increasing.  Hence, the most recent one would have the largest value:

```
select osh.order_id, max(osh.order_status)
from order_status_history osh
group by osh.order_id;
```

If the assumption of increasing statuses is not true, then you can use an aggregation and join:

```
select osh.*
from order_status_history osh join
     (select order_id, max(status_date) as maxsd
      from order_status_history
      group by order_id
     ) o
     on osh.order_id = osh.order_id;
```

As for the text description, you should really be storing this information in a reference table and joining that it in.  (I suspect that is what `order_status` is, but just poorly described.)  Otherwise, you use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when osh.order_status = 100 then 'in-progress'
             when osh.order_status = 100 then 'in-progress'
             when osh.order_status = 1000 then 'completed'
        end)
```

Comment: Thank you! can you also help me figure out how to select corresponding status for max(status_date) for an order?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable . . . I believe that is what these queries do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get status of `order_id` for specified date you can use next query

```
SELECT OS.order_id,
        CASE WHEN 
            (SELECT MAX(OSH.order_status) 
             FROM order_status_history AS OSH
             WHERE OSH.order_id = OS.order_id
                       AND OSH.status_date <= @date)) < 1000
             THEN 'in-progress'
             ELSE 'completed' END status
FROM order_status AS OS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select m.order_id,IF(order_done < order_status,'in-progress (because as of report date, its latest status is '||m.order_done,'completed (because as of report date, its latest status is '||m.order_done) status
    from order_status m left join (select osh.order_id, max(osh.order_status) order_done
    from order_status_history osh
where osh.status_date <'2016-04-01' and osh.status < 1000
    group by osh.order_id) n on m.order_id = n.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that even the current order status is recorded in the history table (based this on the data for order 1):

```
select distinct s.order_id, s.order_status as current_order_status, if(h2.order_status<1000,'in progress','completed') as status_at_report_date
from order_status left join
    (select order_id, max(id) as max_id from order_status_history h1
    where h1.status_date<='2016-04-01') t on t.order_id=s.order_id
    left join order_status_history h2 on t.max_id=h2.id
```